# Unlimited Elements WooCommerce Custom Shop Page Add Variations Dropdown and add to cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to build custom shop page with unlimited elements.

```html
<div class="index screen">         
<div class="overlap-group10">
            <div class="rectangle-24"></div>
            <div class="rectangle-25"></div>
            <img
              class="mask-group-7 mask-group"
              src="https://anima-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/6497732f19428b18c1ef5eb8/releases/649773a2a6421e37ef40da3b/img/mask-group-7@1x.png"
              alt="Mask Group 7"
            />
            <div class="rectangle-23"></div>
              <img
                class="image-9 image"
                src="{{item.product.image}}"
                alt="Image 9"
              />
            <div class="bartek-zieman-14 ttnorms-bold-white-16px">{{item.product.title|raw}}</div>
            <div class="bartek-zieman-15 ttnorms-regular-normal-celeste-12px">BLACK MARKET GOAL EXPLOSION
 
              
  </div>
            <div class="group-16"><div class="bartek-zieman-16 ttnorms-light-white-16px">Cobalt</div></div>
            <div class="path-container-2 path-container-5">
              <img
                class="path-8"
                src="https://anima-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/6497732f19428b18c1ef5eb8/releases/649773a2a6421e37ef40da3b/img/path-8-1@1x.png"
                alt="Path 8"
              />
              <img
                class="path-9"
                src="https://anima-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/6497732f19428b18c1ef5eb8/releases/649773a2a6421e37ef40da3b/img/path-9-1@1x.png"
                alt="Path 9"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="szkolny-chopak-q-4 szkolny-chopak-q-7 ttnorms-medium-white-12px">{{item.product.woo_price|wc_price|raw}}
              
  </div>
          </div>
  
</div>
```

I have achieved to translate adobe xd template to html code but im struggling to add variations dropdown menu on my product cards. All of my products are variables and I'm trying to show variations under dropdown menu and add a add to cart button. I'm also trying to change price and color (right now it's "Cobalt" and static) according to active dropdown. I'd be so glad if I had some help, thanks!